# Make FQL query on form submit and continue or cancel submitting based on query result

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, forms, facebook-fql

I have a small question. I'm not able to continue or cancel form submitting based on FQL query result (if user likes a few pages) in FB Javascript SDK. It's probably because of FB queries are async. Any hints, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's solved by promise pattern.